# R Quantmod GetSymbols Not Connecting

Tags: r, quantmod

I am trying to download daily stock data from Yahoo Finance via the Quantmod package in R. I encounter an error message stating that a connection could not be established.

```
install.packages("quantmod")
library(quantmod)
getSymbols.yahoo(Symbols = "SPY")

Error in new.session() : Could not establish session after 5 attempts
```

Comment: How about `getSymbols(Symbols = "SPY", src='yahoo')`?

Comment: Check your firewall and general internet connection. Verify that you can hit (for example) `https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/quote?symbols=APL` in your browser (not R); it should return/display a JSON structure.

Answer (score 0):

First please check the internet and also check proxy, if any, blocking the connection like `@r2evans` mentioned.

Update QuantMod (using `remotes` package) and try again:

```
remotes::install_github("joshuaulrich/quantmod@358-getsymbols-new.session")
```

Alternatively (using `remotes` or `devtools` packages):

```
# lightweight
remotes::install_github("joshuaulrich/quantmod")

# or
devtools::install_github("joshuaulrich/quantmod")
```

One of these should work..